# Using great expectations for date validation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, great-expectations

We are using great_expectations to validate data using Apache Spark.
We are unable to validate columns which have the DATE or DATETIME type.

We use the below configuration to check date entries in a table if they are recent or not.

```
[
                {
                    "expectation_type": "expect_column_min_to_be_between",
                    "kwargs": {
                        "column": "started",
                        "min_value": "2020-12-13"
                         },
                    "parse_strings_as_datetimes": True
                }]
```

But it throws the error:
`not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Since `str` failed, we tried to use

```
[
            {
                "expectation_type": "expect_column_min_to_be_between",
                "kwargs": {
                    "column": "started",
                    "min_value": datetime.fromisoformat("2020-12-13")
                     },
                "parse_strings_as_datetimes": True
            }]
```

But here we get the same error:
`not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

We also tried it after removing the `parse_strings_as_datetimes` argument but it still throws the same error.

We have also tried asking the great_expectations team in slack, but they didn't respond. Does anyone have a clue what is wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you trying to parse it after converting to a tabular structure (within a `dataframe`)? With that being said, you can leverage the inbuilt `spark` `date` functions and it would be a much easier option

Comment: The problem is date is always considered as a string by great_expectations. So, when great_expectations module compares date in the dataframe to the `min_value`, it always throws: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Comment: I've configured with 'datetime' value in the min_value  and without 'parse_strings_as_datetimes' param and it works

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug. There is an [existing Github Issue open for this](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/4847), and the internal team will be working on it. I also tried searching the Great Expectations Slack and couldn't find a question like this, so for the future, you may want to confirm that you have actually posted the question in the Support channel of the Slack.

Comment: Thanks for linking the github issue to the answer. This problem is exactly what I faced. I have also commented on the github issue.
I will just go ahead and implement a custom expectation for the time being.